# How can i get the src of the <img> inside a dynamic(jquery-created) element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$("#grid").on("click", $("#grid > .items > img"), function () {
  alert($(this).css("src"));
});
```

grid is the parent.i need to get the src of the clicked items's img.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues here:

1. Your [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) syntax is not correct. Instead of passing jQuery object you can simply pass a string.
2. Also, in selector you don't need to pass `#grid` again, as it already points to the parent container when you use: `$("#grid").on("click", ...`
3. Also, [`.css(propertyName)`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) is used to get the value of a computed style property for the first element in the set of matched elements, but here you are not looking for any style property but you are looking for the `src` attribute of an element. So, you need to use [`.attr(attributeName)`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method here instead, as it gets the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

---

So, your updated code will look like:

```
$("#grid").on("click", ".items > img", function() {
  alert($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should actually access the `src` of an `img` attribute. So it would be like:

```
alert($(this).attr("src"));
```